# Get value of last cell in column from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

In Google sheet, when I want to get last value from column A, I use this.

```
=index(A:A,max(row(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))
```

It works perfect. Even if there are spaces in between it skips them. This is exactly how I wanted it. But when I want to refer column from another sheet I changed it to this:

```
=index((AnotherSheetName!A):(AnotherSheetName!A),max(row((AnotherSheetName!A):(AnotherSheetName!A))*((AnotherSheetName!A):(AnotherSheetName!A)<>"")))
```

And with this I am getting error:

```
Error Unknown range name: 
'A'.
```

Not getting any clue for the error as I am just replacing column name with `sheetname!column name`. Can someone please help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notation for ranges in a remote sheet is incorrect, this should work:

```
=index(AnotherSheetName!A:A,max(row(AnotherSheetName!A:A)*(AnotherSheetName!A:A<>"")))
```